# Can the iPod Nano 5th generation take screenshots?

Tags: ipod, screen-capture, ipod-nano

I own a small **iPod nano 5th gen** that I really like.

[image]

In order to try and troubleshoot a small, non-blocking bug that it seems to have, I would like to take screenshots on it - I would assume that storing them and transferring them to a computer wouldn't be a problem, since it shoots videos and has a camera roll.

I couldn't find this info anywhere and I'm wondering if that's even possible, but if it is, I'd like to know how!

**I also accepts answers that offer to recopy the screen of the iPod on a Mac computer, since if I recopy I could easily screenshot there.**
(Maybe with Terminal?)

Comment: It does not "shoot videos" as it has no camera. I don't have a 4th gen, so I can't test this, but have you tried pressing the center button and the power button at the same time? That might mimic what the iPhone and iPad can do.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I am asking about a 5th generation (edited answer) - I wish they had came up with names that make it easier to remember :)

Comment: @TMHahn The question asker was talking about an iPod Nano 5th gen, which does have a camera, and has amended their question as such.

Comment: @fabriced have you tried pressing the center button and power button at the same time? how about the volume down button and power button at the same time?

Comment: John, which one are you calling the power button? There's a "hold" switch on top that you can only toggle on and off, then there's the wheel and the center button.

Comment: @fabriced I never got your comment because you didn't start it with `@JohnRamos`! But anyway, I'm just trying to suggest general ideas here. Since there's no power button, let me now see what I can dig up.

Comment: @fabriced it really doesn't seem like this is possible. There's nothing about it on any forum and the word "screenshot" isn't mentioned once in the user guide. Can you try plugging it into your Mac and opening preview or quicktime, then taking a screenshot on your Mac with CMD-Shift-3?

Comment: John, you mean I can recopy the ipod's screen onto a mac computer? How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry I always forget to tag @JohnRamos

Comment: @fabriced No worries :D. Though I have no experience with iPod Nanos, you can try following the second method on this site (http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/two-different-ways-to-mirror-an-ios-device-to-a-mac--cms-23533) to get your iPod's screen on your Mac. I know it works for iOS devices, just try for the Nano (which kind of runs ios!).

Answer (score 1):

Do what my grandpa would do and record the screen with another camera. :^)

The iPod Nano 5g does **not** run iOS. I'm not aware if it has any kind of undocumented screengrabbing or debugging-over-USB capability. It does have a video output, but only the audio or video content being played is output--it does not mirror the screen; so using an AV cable with capture card to record it would only be useful if the issue you have has to do with video/audio playback.

You're probably already aware that it's unlikely for whatever issue you've encountered to be addressed by Apple. The iPod Nano 5g was released in Sept. 2009, its last software update was in Nov. 2009 (version 1.0.2), and discontinued in Sept. 2010 (so all units would be out of warranty by now).